# Hyperfine structure interval rule only obeyed approximately?

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy

The hyperfine interaction is given by $\Delta E = A \langle I \cdot J \rangle = \frac{A}{2}\left[ F(F+1) - I(I+1) - J(J+1) \right]$. The interval rule is given by:
$$ \frac{\Delta E_{F,F-1}}{\Delta E_{F-1,F-2}} = \frac{F}{F-1} $$

In some emission lines, they don't exactly fit in with the interval rule. Why is it that in some cases this rule is only obeyed approximately?

Comment: It might be helpful to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfine_structure, which states that the above interval rule is observed if I and J are approximately good quantum numbers (i.e. the hyperfine splitting is relatively week).

Comment: So in cases such as l=0 where the fine structure is zero, the hyperfine structure dominates and interval rule doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I think in that case the hyperfine structure would be dependent on the nuclear quadrupole moment. But I'm not an expert on this...